# Redundant data in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, database-normalization

Let's say Microsoft has many CDs and it needs to track (including history) the location of each CD .

So there will probably be a `CDs` table like :

```
CD_ID  | title | ...
_________________________
  ...  | ...   | ...
```

And another table which represents the "`moves`" :

```
CD_ID  | dateMoved | DestinationCountryID |
___________________________________________
  ...  |   ...     | ...
```

And here is my problem :

If Microsoft wants to know where is cd `Y` is currently at :

It can scan the `moves` table and get its last `county`.

But ( and here is my question) :

*Something* inside my head tells me that I should add a column to the `CDs` table to be like this :

```
CD_ID  | title | CurrentCountryID | ...
________________________________________
  ...  | ...   |          ...     | ...
```

So it would be more descriptive per Cd Item. (and easy to find).

The `CurrentCountryID` will be updated after each move.

**But**

This will cause redaundant data !

cuz now we have 2 places which represents its current location.

Am I right ? should I add this column ?

*(NB if you gonna ask about quantity : lets say we have millions of cd's)*

Comment: @MitchWheat yes. I already added the tag. I guess its about normalization. ( plus best practice solution)

Comment: if the question is "should I normalise?" the answer is "Yes"!

Comment: @MitchWheat my db is normalised indeed. I just ask for that particular scenario ! should I add the column or not. ( and scan each time - the moves table)

Comment: Why not make a stored procedure for CurrentCountry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do really depends on your needs. If you're going to look up the current country often and performance needs to be good, I would put the current country on the CDs table. Otherwise you will have to query the moves table every time and get the max date - not very good for performance.

If, on the other hand, you rarely need that information, I would normalise it and leave it only in moves table.